# Which is the best Approach or Best Practices to leave properties files in a Separated Java Project?

Tags: java, web-applications, properties, configuration

I have a project that will be separate as:

- a) **Business Layer** ( containing all the core Java classes and some configurations (services, etc) )  and
- b) **Presentation Layer** (containing all the web structure based on Spring webflow and also all the configuration files on it.  So in the process of development we have several properties files spread in the `java/main/src` under a `resource.properties.*` package  and we have other properties in the web structure under  `WEB-INF/conf`  and `WEB-INF/i18n` (which are label messages for the screen)..so my questions are the following:

  1. It's correct to leave the properties files inside of
     `java/main/src` under packages that later will be under `classes`
     folder in the webapp?.
  2. Which is the best approach to leave all the
     properties files in one place let say *`WEB-INF/configurations`* ? or
     leave some properties files of business layer in one place and some
     properties files from presentation layer in another place?
  3. Which is the best approach to have this properties in a best way to
     install the webapp?, deliver the properties in a JAR file and
     include it in the WAR or EAR? that allows us to modify on the fly
     and include in the war without deploy the entire application... or which is the best or used approach to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you use a build tool like Maven or Ant?

Comment: we use jenkins and ANT to compile ...

Answer (score 1):

I've found in helpful to separate properties into two categories:

1. Properties for conveniently changing application look and behavior
2. Properties for environment-specific settings (for example DEV vs. PRODUCTION)

Category #1 can be embedded in your WAR files wherever makes sense.  In `WEB-INF/classes` is a popular place, but putting them in `META-INF` in jar files can also work well.  It is worth choosing a standard you like and sticking with it.  The bottom line is that these files are changed during development; they are not changed after deployment and remain the same at the system is released.

Category #2 should always be separate from the deployable.  Ideally, environment-specific properties should be deployed only when they change.  It is really a configuration-management (CM) decision where they live.  Developers need to supply the basic versions of these configuration files and CM should edit them when they are deployed to specific environments (QA, PRE-PROD, PROD).  In situations where delegation of duties is mandated (e.g. where SOX applies), the production version of the properties files should never be touched or seen by developers.  I've seen a lot of cases where the different versions (DEV/QA/PROD) of these files are maintained by developers and kept in source control  That's not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Charles for your comment!. In the category #2 we use separate configuration layer to include the same properties for each environment using Jenkins to overwrite those. The problem arises when Configuration Management later on the release want to deliver and change the configuration (properties files) to the customers and makes a hard process to follow if you have all the properties files spread in different places ... so if we have a separate configuration project that only have properties files should works under a best practice? what is your experience with that Charles? Thanks in adv

Comment: Ah. You have a third category: application customization that is _provided_ by developers to set at deploy time by the customer. My favored approach is to use a properties file outside the deployable, but make sure that there are reasonable defaults for anything that can be set.  If the file isn't there, or it a particular option is not set, the application still works.  This is pretty easy to do: have an internal properties file with the default.  The location of the external file can be set with a system property in the JVM opts.  This minimizes the CM impact.  Does that help?

Comment: Exactly Charles, we have some properties where we configure let say URLs backends (services), application configs, etc.) and those are being called by spring properties implementation... If I understand correctly your approach is to use an external JAR or WAR outside of the deployable and point in the application to JVM opts to recover the properties right?... it would be better than JVM opts use JNDI ?  do you know if with JNDI works? Thanks

Comment: Pretty close.  I was just talking about a simple flat file for properties, not one wrapped in a JAR.  That makes the files easy to manage for the customer.  I guess finding the file with JNDI is an option, but it seems like that might over-complicate things. If you can determine a directory from available data, you can designate a particular directory and look at all `.properties` files in it.  For example, if you are running under JBOSS, you might use `System.getProperty("jboss.home")` and then tack `/properties` onto it and look there.

Answer (score 0):

I think its good to have a separate source folder 'resources' and keep all the properties file there. These also make sure that the property files don't get mixed up the source code.

Comment: Thanks Aditya ...so you mean in `src/main/java/resources`   or in `src/main/resources` ?